# What's the correct way of modifying a control through its DOM object?

Tags: sapui5

Sometimes we want to add some custom refinement.
For example, I would like to add an underline to TextView. So I want to set the bottom border to "1px solid black", as in the following code:

http://jsbin.com/gozidiqote/edit?html,css,js,output
What's the practice of achieving such an aim?

Comment: you can try adding a styleclass to the textview. Something like ` new sap.ui.core.TextView({text:'awesome text'}).addStyleClass('borderBottom') `  After that, implement the style in a css and include css file for the application in index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way is to alter the css-definitions or rather overwrite them with yours.

Which one depends on your case, if you want to add the line to all TextViews you should use its class, if you want to add it only to this you can give an id to it and attach the style with that.

#### Using CSS with id (easier):

You need to give your TextView an id, then define the style for that id

```
new sap.ui.core.TextView("someRandomId", {
    text: "hello world"
});

#someRandomId {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

#### Using CSS with class:

First you need to find out, which class every TextView has. To find it you need to look into the "live-dom" of your page (eg. with firefox you right-click the text and press <kbd>q</kbd>,. the highlighted `span` is created by the TextView). When you found the class you define a css-style for it.
In the case of the TextView each has the class `sapUiTv`, so you can use that one:

```
.sapUiTv {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```